# Нужны ли запятые при уточнении?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли запятые в этих обстоятельствах?

"... над открытой емкостью для бурового раствора - на расстоянии не более 0,2 м над ее верхней кромкой, а также рядом с емкостью (,) на высоте 0.5 м над полом"

"у вибросита - на расстоянии не более 1 м от него (,) на высоте не более 0.5 м над ним"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"... над открытой емкостью для бурового раствора - на расстоянии не более 0,2 м над ее верхней кромкой, а также рядом с емкостью (,) на высоте 0.5 м над полом"- можно ставить(как пояснение), можно не ставить(если нет акцента на уточняющее пояснение и произносится без паузы). Я бы не поставила, потому что в первой части такая же конструкция без запятой. В параллельных конструкциях обычно одинаковы и знаки препинания для полного соответствия.

"у вибросита - на расстоянии не более 1 м от него (,) на высоте не более 0.5 м над ним"- запятая также факультативна, но здесь можно поставить И (на расстоянии не более 1 м от него И на высоте не более 0.5 м над ним), поэтому запятая более уместна.

Comment: Спасибо. Как я посмотрела в интернете, запятую почему-то обычно не ставят, хотя это уточнение.

Comment: Выбор знаков должен максимально прояснять содержание текста, делать его удобным для чтения и понимания. Правила дают автору определенную степень свободы (что-то похожее на  валютный коридор в области финансов). Думаю, что работать надо внутри такого коридора, максимально соблюдая интересы читателей информации. К сожалению, формальная наука построена так, что она предлагает нам единичные образцы для подражания, не всегда удобно их копировать один к одному.

Comment: Это Вы кому?

Comment: Это Аленке, она же правит тексты (ответ на ее замечание). Это общее пожелание нашим корректорам. Текст должен быть таким, чтобы его было удобно читать, и ЭТО ГЛАВНОЕ. В этом случае он, как правило, вписывается в орфографические правила. Вот, к примеру,  в архитектуре красота - это не только эстетика, но и гарантия правильности и качества конструкции. А если текст править только по Розенталю, ища похожие примеры, то критерий ясности/качества отодвигается на второй план.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы оставила знаки препинания без изменения. Все обстоятельства имеют уточняющий характер, для обособления их можно использовать тире или запятую. Выбор тире связан с наличием других запятых в середине предложения.

"у вибросита - на расстоянии не более 1 м от него, на высоте не более 0.5 м над ним". Здесь отношения можно рассматривать как однородные с перечислением координат установки.